# How to query site DNS A-Record?

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

```
nslookup -type=ns b92.net a.root-servers.net
```

I got this

```
Server:     a.root-servers.net
Address:    198.41.0.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find b92.net: No answer

Authoritative answers can be found from:
net nameserver = a.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = b.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = c.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = d.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = e.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = f.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = g.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = h.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = i.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = j.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = k.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = l.gtld-servers.net.
net nameserver = m.gtld-servers.net.
a.gtld-servers.net  internet address = 192.5.6.30
b.gtld-servers.net  internet address = 192.33.14.30
c.gtld-servers.net  internet address = 192.26.92.30
```

If I try

```
nslookup -type=ns b92.net
```

I got private Ip adress as output

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
b92.net nameserver = primary.b92.net.
b92.net nameserver = ns2.b92.net.
```

I am new to `lookup`.

My goal is to receive A resource type.

How to make the right DNS query?

Comment: The root servers know only about TLDs, so will not give you the reply when querying with a second level domain name. They give you a referral to the TLD nameservers you need to query. PS: if you can prefer dig over nslookup, it is simpler and more correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let's go through what you did and what you want to do:

`nslookup -type=ns b92.net a.root-servers.net`

This asks `nslookup` look up the **Name Server** records for **b92.net** from **a.root-servers.net**

Next you tried:

`nslookup -type=ns b92.net`

This asks `nslookup` look up the **Name Server** records for **b92.net** but using your default servers.

But you wanted the **A record** for **b92.net**

So to get that result, you'll need to run `nslookup b92.net`